# R assign ID to polygon's in sfc_POLYGON for plotting

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a spatial dataframe with 6 features and i want to plot them as different colours, but i cant see any attributes to call them by? if they are not there can i create an id for example?

I was plotting the spatial file as below but id like to give the 6 features different colours;

```
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = pols_3_sf,col="black",fill="white") 

> class(pols_3_sf)
[1] "sfc_POLYGON" "sfc"   

> pols_3_sf
Geometry set for 6 features 
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -15.2506 ymin: 48.0494 xmax: 1.2506 ymax: 62.4506
geographic CRS: WGS 84
First 5 geometries:
POLYGON ((-9.4494 48.0994, -9.4494 48.0494, -9....
POLYGON ((-15.0494 55.6994, -15.0494 55.6494, -...
POLYGON ((-11.0994 57.2994, -11.0994 57.2494, -...
POLYGON ((-13.9494 58.6994, -13.9506 58.6994, -...
POLYGON ((-9.9994 59.0994, -9.9994 59.0494, -10...
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use the rownames of your input data frame as the fill variable. It would look something like this:

```r
library(sf) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(dplyr)

nc <- read_sf(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf")) %>% 
  select(geometry) %>% 
  tail()

ggplot(nc) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = rownames(nc)), color = "black") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]